# How to solve ECONNRESET while installing Electron?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I am trying to install electron but getting ECONNRESET error despite trying multiple things :

1. tried installing globally
2. tried removing the proxy.
3. tried a mirror address but not sure if the address was incorrect or some other issue.
   Errors

> Error: read ECONNRESET ←[90m    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead
>   (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)←[39m {   errno:
>   ←[32m'ECONNRESET'←[39m,   code: ←[32m'ECONNRESET'←[39m,   syscall:
>   ←[32m'read'←[39m }
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! electron@6.0.8
>
> postinstall: `node install.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm
>
> ERR! Failed at the electron@6.0.8 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is
>
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>
> C:\Users\anoopku\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-11T07_20_01_482Z-debug.log

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtQf1.png)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
set "ELECTRON_MIRROR=http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/" && npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question, instead of posting code-only answer.

Comment: Without knowing anything about `taobao.org`, this looks VERY unsafe to me..